# Конвертировать стринг в дату SQLite

Tags: sql, строки, дата

Есть ли способ конвертировать String в формат date? date в данном случае  String.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-08-12' AND '2016-
12-12'";
```

Comment: Есть, конечно. А конкретная реализация зависит от диалекта SQL - в каждой СУБД свои функции.

Comment: cast('2016-08-12' as date)?

Comment: `date('2016-08-12')`

Comment: `datetime()` вернет дату формата _YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS_

Comment: В SQLite нет типа для представления даты и времени.